# Convert a point on a flat 2D web-mercator map image to a Coordinate

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, google-maps, convert, web-mercator

I have an image of a map and a point marked onto it. I have those coordinates (as a percentage) inside the image of the point. Now I'd like to know the coordinate (latitude/longitude) that this point would have.

For better understanding what I mean I made a little scribble inside a map.
To my point for example is at 10% East and 30% North. Getting the longitude is easy as I just need to take 10% of 180° and I have my 18° East. Great.
But as the latitude is a projected ellipsoid it's not that easy any more.

I found an other question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171142/converting-x-y-on-mercator-to-wgs84-latitude-and-longitude) that pointed to this e-book here: https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf
On page 44 there should be the explanation and on page 267 a sample, but I just can't find the correct coordinates using that equation.

[image: map with scribbles]

I would be super happy if anybody could give me pseudo code or something on how to calculate a lat/lng coordinate from my percentage coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Inverse transformations section of the spherical [Mercator projection Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Inverse_transformations).

It says: `φ = 2 * tan⁻¹[exp(y/R)] - π/2`

`φ` is the latitude in radians (you can multiply by *180/π* at the end, to convert to decimal degrees).
`tan⁻¹` is the inverse tangent function.
`exp` is the exponential function.
`y` is your *y* coordinate (0.3 in the question case).
`R` is the radius of the sphere. Your circumference (length of the Equator) is 2, because *x* coordinates go from -1 to 1, so your radius is 1 / π. You can simplify `y/R` as `y*π`.

Python code:

```python
import math

y = 0.3

# C = 2*pi*R = 2
# R = 2/(2*pi) = 1/pi
# y/R = y*pi

# lat = 2 * arctan(exp(y/R)) - pi/2

lat = (2 * math.atan( math.exp( y * math.pi)) - math.pi / 2) * 180 / math.pi

print(lat)
```

Prints: `47.42214099287614`

Comment: If this Formula is correct, why does it result in `85.05112877980659` for `y = 1`? One would expect `90`.

Comment: Nobody expects to see the poles in the Mercator projection, since they are projected to infinity.